# Usage of "may" instead of "might" in the past context

Tags: grammar, past-tense, modal-verbs, books

I came across the following sentence while reading "A Clash of Kings" book by George R. R. Martin:

> Whitetree was the fourth village they had passed, and it had been the
> same in all of them. The people were gone, vanished with their scant
> possessions and whatever animals they **may** have had. None of the
> villages showed any signs of having been attacked

Why is the "may" word used here instead of "might"? I thought that "may" can be used only in the present tense and have never seen it used in the past context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about dialects A and B, which are differentiated by reference to constructions like:

> [1] *I thought it might rain before we got home.*
>
> [2] *I thought it may rain before we got home.*

In the older Dialect A (which I speak) [2] is ungrammatical (just like *"I thought I can finish the book before I got home"): [1], with "might" is required.

In Dialect B, [2] is possible as well as [1]. In Dialect A, "might" is undoubtedly the preterite counterpart of "may", just as "could" is of "can" because it is the form required in backshift. In Dialect B there's no basis for retaining (from earlier stages of the language) the analysis of "might" as the preterite of "may": it must be a distinct lexeme.

One factor facilitating this linguistic change is that "might" even in Dialect A is hardly used in the primary sense of the preterite, to indicate past time: we usually say "was/were allowed" rather than "might" for past time permission, e.g. "He told me I/we might go".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, would I be right if I said that nowadays we can say "I thought it may rain before we got home" as well as "I thought I can finish the book before I got home"?

Comment: I read this article https://www.enago.com/academy/may-or-might/ where they say that "I thought I may go to the game" is incorrect, and now I'm really confused :(

Comment: Yes, as I said, those examples are acceptable to speakers of Dialect B.

Comment: @Denis Quark and Svartvik did basic tests on acceptability, proving almost conclusively that until there is an artificially imposed legally binding standardisation of 'correct grammar' (and even this doesn't work as is seen in France), there are always going to be areas of divided usage in English (acceptable to some practises Anglophones but unacceptable to others). They came up with the equally unsatisfactory gradience model of acceptability (a sentence being say 40% acceptable).

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, I understand it. I'm more confused that different official sources provide different information on which grammar is correct, not mentioning specific regions or dialects

Comment: As to the sentence "I thought I can finish the book before I got home", it seems very unusual for me, though I have read about 10 english books (mostly American books) and tons of other content. Does it seem unusual for you too?

Comment: @Denis You asked about "may/might", which is what my answer was intended to deal with. As so often happens on ELU, this thread is drifting off-topic.

Comment: The rule I go by is to use _might_ when the uncertainty was in the past and _may_ when it still exists (which I suppose is Bill's Dialect A). We don't know what animals those people had, to the author used _may_. I always find it jarring when a newspaper report says "If this had not happened, he may not have died' when we know that the unfortunate person _did_ die.

Comment: @Denis Essentially, BillJ is saying that some (and this includes well educated native speakers) will say that both (1) and (2) are acceptable while others will say that only (1) is acceptable. And the Quark/Svartvik research shows that this is far from being an isolated example of such disagreements.